# Using ncurses in c language

Tags: scroll, screen, ncurses

I'm using ncurses in one of my application in unix server.
My application is in such a way that it displays different set of information.

So I have created different pads to display each content.
Is there a way to use scroll option for these pads at a stretch?

As of now ncurses is limited to screen size, if I have display 3 or more pads at the same time it is not possible because it exceeds the screen size.

Is there any way to do to implement scroll using ncurses in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

ncurses (any curses library) supports *overlapping* windows.  You do not have to tile (subdivide) the screen.

If you design your program to allow the user to select different views of the data, you can have multiple windows on the screen which use most of it.

For instance, the [dialog](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/dialog.html) program in this screenshot is showing overlapping windows (using [`touchwin`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_touch.3x.html) and [`wrefresh`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_refresh.3x.html)).  The tab character makes it switch focus to the next window:

[image]